# Sound changed to muted on boot-up?

Tags: system

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my iBook G4 and every time i reboot the volume is changed to mute and i have to turn it up again. How can i make it so it automatically unmutes before lightdm and Gnome 2.

Video Example=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8zV5-8BJdo

Comment: go to sound setting and make it 100% then restart and check..

Comment: I have the same problem. A friend of mine told me that it's a compatibility issue between my sound card and linux systems but of course I cannot assure you he's right.